# Run Multiple htaccess RewriteRule together

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have taken over developing a php website which has been developed by different people over years. There are some “folders” and files which have been posted/mailed etc as direct links over years, so i have to keep them functioning without changing the links or the contents. But i also need to at least track the visits -and do some other db things to integrate them into my new system-

The main site is under public_html/

One of the “real” folders is under public_html/c/

under folder c, there are lots of subfolders, some goes one step inside some more. And the links are various, like:

example.com/c/f1/index.htm

example.com/c/f2/index.html

example.com/c/f3/index5.php

example.com/c/f3/f31/index.php

or some pdf files etc under c/ and some pages might contain forms which need to be submitted to itself etc..

i have tried lots of things but couldn’t figure out the right way..

I need to get into the middle of every request under folder c/ and call my file public_html/dostuff.php first, with the param of the requested link, and after that, let the process continue -show the page-.

This is my final htaccess content under /c/

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dostuff.php?url=$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

#### some of the other trials…

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dostuff.php?url=$1
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dostuff.php?url=$1 [C]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dostuff.php?url=$1
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

dostuff.php works, i’ve even replaced its content with empty php tag 
to avoid coding errors get into way.. and those two rewriterule work if there’s only one of them. but not one after another... where am i doing wrong??